# How can I concat Date field and Float one to get a DateTime field?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

```
T2 = fields.Float()
date = fields.Date()
```

for example if T2= 09:00
and date =12/09/2017

the result should be 12/09/2017 09:00

Comment: why  T2= 09:00 is float?

Comment: bcz <field name="T2" widget="float_time" /> gives something like 00:00

Comment: I mean how 09:00 could be float type

Comment: it is 9,0 but on the tree view if we use widget="float_time" it appears like 09:00

Comment: widget="float_time" lets the users see and enter values using the familiar HH:MM format but for example if the user enters 8:30 the value stored in the database will be 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could convert T2 to str and combine two together

```
  T2= "09,00"
  date = datetime.date(2017,9,12)
  date_str = date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
  print date_str
  date_str += T2
  print date_str
  print datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y%H,%M')


12/09/2017
12/09/201709,00
2017-09-12 09:00:00
```

or if t2 is float type

```
  T2= 8.5
  date = datetime.date(2017,9,12)
  print datetime.datetime.fromordinal(date.toordinal()) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=T2*3600)

2017-09-12 08:30:00
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Comment: @SOS-Mona you date is string type, so you need to use the first one, add all string together then convert to datetime

Comment: ValueError: time data '2017-10-136:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: @SOS-Mona you need to check the format. your pattern is not same as string. There is a space between %d and %H in pattern, but no space in string.